# Wiring in wall light and shelly v1

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, smart-switch

I'm wanting to add a shelly v1 to one of our wall lights but after taking it off I can't work out what is happening here! The wiring doesn't seem to match any diagrams I can find, what is this called and why isn't the light permanently on?
[image: wiring]

Comment: why not always on? there's a switch between the photo and the breaker box. That looks like a typical fixture box. Wouldn't you want the shelly replacing a switch? If you are going to use it at the fixture instead, yes, you will want constant power to the fixture.

Comment: The switch has three cables going in and is pretty full so was hoping to put it in light, but I don't get where the two wires are going, the diagrams i can find for end of a loop for example have a switched live in the light but not sure if I have that here, and ones with loop to another light have thress wires? Like as they join if it was going to another light it would only work if this one was on? If it doesn't then why doesn't it return on same cable?

Comment: Think of it as a splice to simplify. If you want to switch only that light, splice after the "busbar". If you want to control all the lights on the run, splice the dark blue and red wire into the shelly. Note that you can't use the wall switch after this, so it should be removed for human/EMT factors.

Comment: There is only one light from that switch so is it effectively just joining the two cables together at the point of the light for some reason?

Comment: yes, perhaps there used to be a another light, or there's a switched outlet (which might not be up to code). try disconnecting that half (brown, light blue) and see if it's missed anywhere. if not, you can ignore it.

Comment: Yeah that still works, I think that solves my confusion thanks! Actually looking at room I think there was another light on the other side of the fireplace but the previous owner has put a built in tv unit over it!

Comment: @DanTurner -- where are you on this planet btw?

Comment: @DanTurner -- also, can you post a photo of how the existing wall switch location is wired?

Comment: You need to look back at the switch or the connectors in the wall. There’s more than 1 ways of wiring , power to the switch , power to the fixture. It appears you have the switched power coming to this location any going out to ceiling light?

Comment: @EdBeal the wire coloring and metric cross-section labeling indicate Europe.

Comment: I do know this but there is no difference in how electrons flow, they use brown for a hot and blue for a neutral, since the light is not always on there is a switch. We can’t see the splices in the wall but there is not much other that we can say without the switch & box wiring.